# In Neo4J, how do I match a subgraph, but filter nodes that are in another subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

My graph is a directed acyclical graph. I would like to query for the subgraph of a given parent node, but then filter out subgraphs that have a relationship to another parent node. I created an image to illustrate.

For example I would like to select the subgraph `(C)-[r]->(D)`, but exclude `(B)-[r]->(E)` because it is a child of `(A)`.

I have written the following Cypher query, which includes a call to `apoc.path.subpgrahAll()`, it filters out (B), but it doesn't filter out nodes like `(E)`

```
MATCH (n {id: 'C'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {relationshipFilter: 'CONNECTED>'})
YIELD nodes, relationships
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH node
WHERE SIZE(()-[:CONNECTED]->(node)) = 1
RETURN node
```

[image]

Comment: So, you actually want to filter out nodes that have a relationship to *any* parent node (not just "another parent node"), correct? Also, how do we identify that a node is a "parent" node to be used for filtering purposes?

Comment: Not quite what I was thinking, in this example I would like to select C and D as a subgraph starting from C, B should be excluded because it has another parent node besides C; A. Parent nodes have an outgoing relationship to a child node.. refer to the drawing.

Comment: OK. The wording could be interpreted in multiple ways, and I picked the "wrong" one :-).

Comment: To be consistent with your diagram, shouldn't your `MATCH` clause specify 'A' instead of 'C'?

Comment: No quite, because the diagram is the entire graph, everything. I am just trying to select the subgraph starting from C. A is only there to signify that B has another parent.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {relationshipFilter: 'CONNECTED>'}) YIELD nodes, relationships
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH node
WHERE SIZE((node)<-[:CONNECTED]-()) = 1
RETURN node
```

*By the way, in Cypher patterns, you need to precede a relationship type with a colon, which was one of the problems (but not the main one) with your query.*

Comment: This solution is close, but if I use this on an example with more nodes, it doesn't hold up, because it includes leaf nodes of nodes that have multiple parents. I'm going to update my question to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for any nodes in one of your subgraphs to have incoming `CONNECTED ` relationships from outside that subgraph?

Comment: Yes, in that case I would want to exclude those nodes.